# How can I prevent Micrometer from adding _total suffix to Counter metric name

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, prometheus, spring-micrometer

In my code I define my custom (counter) metric as follows:

```
Counter.builder("request_count")
            .tags("method","GET")
            .tags("path","/my/test/path")
            .register(meterRegistry)
            .increment();
```

You'll note the metric name is defined as **request_count** However when I run the application the metric is being published as follows:

```
# HELP request_count_total  
# TYPE request_count_total counter
request_count_total{method="GET",path="/my/test/path"} 1.0
```

Note the **_total** suffix being appended to the metric name. Apparently this is being cause by the default `PrometheusNamingConvention` and thus I override this class and provide a custom `name()` implementation which explicitly omits the process of appending the **_total** suffix. However this **STILL** results in the metric being published with the suffix.

On attaching a debugger to the application and tracing through the code, I determined that this is because any defined custom NamingConvention class, in respect of the counter metric, is ultimately ignored as the internal `PrometheusMeterRegistry` class defines a `CollectorRegistry` which updates all counter metric names to include the **_total** suffix, just before the metric is published. Here a snippet from the `CollectorRegistry.collectorNames()` method that undertakes the renaming:

```
 while(var4.hasNext()) {
        Collector.MetricFamilySamples family = (Collector.MetricFamilySamples)var4.next();
        switch (family.type) {
            case COUNTER:
                names.add(family.name + "_total");
                names.add(family.name + "_created");
                names.add(family.name);
                break;
```

Thus, it would seem to me that, the **only** conceivable option at this point would be to use the `PrometheusMeterRegistry` class directly; it's constructor allows for the specification of a `CollectorRegistry` instance and ergo I should be able to pass in a custom implementation of this class that does not undertake this renaming operation. My question essentially is:

1)Aside from tying down the Micometer to a single implementation (i.e prometheus) are there any other down sides to this approach?

2)Could you point me to any documentation that provides examples of making use of the `PrometheusMeterRegistry` directly?

Comment: This is probably none of my business but breaking conventions must have a solid reason behind it. This suffix makes it easier for people and tools (such as Grafana) to identify with what kind of data you're dealing with, and a counter is one of those things when it's best to know that it is indeed a counter. I hope the effort you are putting into this and the troubles you may cause to whoever will inherit this solution are well worth it, otherwise I'd rather suggested to drop the idea.